# Run a module when module name is in a variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to run modules from a directory. A simplified version of my project tree would be:

```
main.py
modules/
|_ a/
|  |_ a.py
|  |_ __init__.py
|_ b/
|  |_ b.py
|  |_ __init__.py
|_ __init__.py
```

Each module in `modules/` has an empty `__init__.py` and a `run()` method that does some stuff in `<module-name>.py`

From `main.py` I would like to load all modules, and then run a module by passing it's name as parameter to a function. For example what I would like to do from `main.py`:

```
def runModule(module_name):
    # pseudo-codish
    from modules import "module_name"
    "module_name.run()" 

runModule(a)
```

I've googled a bit but can't seem to find a way this would work. Is this even possible? I'm working with Python3 but would welcome a Python2 solution for guidance even.

Comment: For the record: a *module* is a single python file, while a folder containing python files is a *package*, accompanied by a (can be empty) file named __init__.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

```
def run_module(module_name):
    mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    mod.run()
```